# Finitely generated torsion-free module which is not torsionless

Tags: commutative-algebra, examples-counterexamples

> Let $R$ be a Noetherian ring. Does there exist a finitely generated torsion-free module which is not torsionless?

If $R$ is a domain then the answer is no. More generally, if $Q$ is the total ring of fractions of $R$ and $M\otimes Q$ is a free $Q$-module, then the answer is no. But I can't show $M$ is torsionless in the general case nor have I been able to think of an example where it isn't. It may be worth noting that in this case, $M$ is torsionless if and only if it is a submodule of a finite rank free $R$-module.

Comment: Could you add the definition of “torsionless”?

Comment: Wikipedia has a page about this: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torsionless_module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is positive.

Let $R=K[[X,Y,Z]]/(X^2,XY,XZ)$ and $M=R/(x,y)$. Then every $R$-module is torsion-free (since every non-invertible element of $R$ is a zero-divisor). On the other side, $M$ is not torsionless. Otherwise $\operatorname{Ass}M\subseteq\operatorname{Ass}R$, which is false.